# Looping through nested list in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

JSON Object

```
const users = [{
"name":"Mark",
"age":30,
"isActive" : true,
"cars":{ Owned : ["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"], Rented : ["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]}
},{
"name":"Mistry",
"age":30,
"isActive" : true,
"cars":{ Owned : ["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"], Rented : ["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]}
},{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"isActive" : false,
"cars":{ Owned : ["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"], Rented : ["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]}
}];
```

My Approach:

Typescript

```
let rentedCars:any[]=[];
let ownedCars:any[]=[];
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  const cars = users[0].cars;
  for (let i = 0; i < cars.Owned.length; i++) {
    ownedCars.push(cars.Owned[i]);
  }
for (let j = 0; j < cars.Rented.length; j++) {
    rentedCars.push(cars.Rented[j]);
  }
}
```

Trying to add all the rented and owned cars list in separate list, The above code works, but is there any more efficient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with an `Array.reduce`.
E.g.

```
let cars = { rentedCars: [], ownedCars: [] };
users.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
  acc.rentedCars = acc.rentedCars.concat(curr.cars.Rented);
  acc.ownedCars = acc.ownedCars.concat(curr.cars.Owned);
  return acc;
}, cars);
```

I've not tested it, but I think that would achieve something like what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

As a first idea i should propose something like this:

```
let rentedCars: Set<any> = new Set();
let ownedCars: Set<any> = new Set();
users.forEach((user) => {
  user.cars.Owned.forEach((ownedCar) => ownedCars.add(ownedCar));
  user.cars.Rented.forEach((rentedCar) => rentedCars.add(rentedCar));
});
```

it use the `forEach` function that shorts the code but i also used `Set` to remove the duplicate of your list

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.

```
rentedCars = users.reduce((array,user)=>{
    return [...array,...user.cars.Rented]
},[])

ownedCars = users.reduce((array,user)=>{
    return [...array,...user.cars.Owned]
},[])
```

in case you want to remove duplicated items

```
rentedCars= [...new Set(rentedCars)];
ownedCars= [...new Set(ownedCars)];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using map and reduce and concatenate to flat array**

1. map to loop through (gives array of arrays)
2. reduce to arrive at single value (reduce array)
3. concate totalcars with currentcar (flat array)

   rentedCars: any[] = [];
   ownedCars: any[] = [];

```
separate() {
    
    this.rentedCars = this.users.map(x => x.cars.Rented).reduce((totalcars,currentcar)=>{
     return totalcars.concat(currentcar);
    },[]);
    
    
    this.ownedCars = this.users.map(x => x.cars.Owned).reduce((totalcars,currentcar)=>{
      return totalcars.concat(currentcar);
     },[]);    
  }
```

**Even more simpler**

You map get array of array then directly use [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method (introduced in ES2019)  to flatten the arrays, although it is only available in Node.js starting with version 11, and not at all in Internet Explorer.

```
separate() {
this.rentedCars = this.users.map(x => x.cars.Rented).flat(1);
this.ownedCars = this.users.map(x => x.cars.Owned).flat(1);
}
```